# Proving that every group of order 48 is not simple

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but I´m trying with a different approach(I think).

The proof it´s divided in two parts:
Let G be a simple group of order 48.

1)If $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are the 2-sylows of $G$, let $H$ $\in \{S_i \cap S_j : i \neq j \}$ so that H has maximum order. Prove that $|H|>1$.

2)Prove that $N_G(H)$ (the normalizer) has only one 2-sylow. It´s suggested to reduce it to the absurd and conclude that H is normal in G.

For 1) I have concluded that $|H|=8$, and I arrived to that conclusion because $|S_iS_j|=\frac{|S_i||S_j|}{|S_i\cap S_j|}$, so if the order of the intersection is $1,2$ or $4$, $|S_iS_j|\ge 48 $.

For 2) I have a lot of arguments but I didn´t arrive to any conclusions. If I assume that there is more that 1 2-sylow ($n_2>1$) , and because $n_2 | m$, where m is coprime with 2 , I conclude that m=3. So, $|N_G(H)|=2^i3$, and $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$. If $i=4$ then the order of the normalizer is 48 so it´s normal, and that is absurd. So $i\neq 4$.
I have also noticed that $n_2 =1(mod 2)$ and $n_2|3$ so $n_2=3$ (because $n_2>1$).

Am I on the right track? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, now realize that $H\triangleleft S_1,S_2$, as $[S_i:H]=2$, so $S_1,S_2\subset N_G(H)$. Now, this implies that $|N_G(H)|\geq16+16-8=24$. But, this means $N_G(H)$ is either the whole $G$ or is normal in $G$ since it has index 2. This allows you to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! That´s surely a nice proof, but not the one I was looking for

Comment: The cyclic group of order $48$ is not simple. That proves the statement in the title.

Comment: @DerekHolt I´m trying to see that every group of order 48 is not simple, whether is cyclic or not

Comment: @DerekHolt ... Every group of order 48, not just the cyclic one lol.

Comment: @DonThousand I was just answering the question that was asked! If I was grading an exam, and there was a question "prove that a group of order $48$ is not simple", and somebody answered "the cyclic group of order $48$ is not simple because it has the cyclic group of order $24$ as a proper normal subgroup", then I would feel pobliged to give it full marks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done more easily. Although this does not fully relate to the problems in your proof, I still wanted to share this proof. I hope this answer also helps you

First, we have that $48 = 2^4 \cdot 3$. For the prime $p|48$, let $N_p$ be the number of Sylow-2 groups in $G$.

Now, if we have that $N_p=1$ from some $p$, then we must have that the unique Sylow $p$-group in $G$is normal. Also note that is has order $p$, so it is not $G$ nor $\{e\}$. Therefore, for this case, we conculde that $G$ is not simple.

Then, we have $N \equiv 1\mod{2}$ and $N_2 |3$, so $N_2$ must be equal to either $1$ or $3$. Hopefully, it is clear that if we have that $N_p=1$, we are done, by our previous argument.

Hence, we need to consider the other case, namely $N_p = 3$. Let $Y$ denote the set of Sylow-2 groups. We can write a homomorphism $\varphi : G \to S_Y$ given by sending $a \in G$ to conjugation $\gamma$ by $a$. Then, the kernel of $\varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and hence if $G$ is simple, it has to either consist of $\{e\}$ or all of $G$. Note, the first case is impossible, since $\#G = 48 > 6 = \#S_Y$. This means that all Sylow-2 groups are fixed by conjugation.

Now, the latter is inconsistent with Sylow's theorem (by simply recalling the theorem). Hence, we can conclude that $G$ is not simple

Comment: I mean, this is precisely the proof (albeit written better in the other answer) on the linked version of this question, the point is to aid OP in solving it in OP's way.

Comment: Sorry, missed that!

Comment: could you explain if you refer to a specific subgroup by the notation  is $S_{\gamma}$?